# login fails in first attempt each time in sql server ssms (Login time out expire)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing connection timeout expired error while my first attempt to login in SQL server.
I am able to logged in successfully when I tried to log in again the second time.
SQL server Remote login time out is 20 sec and locks 0.
What was the issue,please help me.

What changes should i do in SSMS for SQL server?

Thanks in advance.

I have check Instance properties remote desktop check.
I have checked SQL server configuration manager in network configurations and it has TCP\IP, Namedpipes,shared memory and VIA is enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://serverfault.com/questions/179898/sql-server-timeout-on-first-attempt

Comment: I've seen something similar when working across domains making domain name resolution an issue. Try adding ".domain_name.local" (without the quotes) to the server name.

Comment: I have allowed 1433 port number from SQL Server Network Configuration in SQL server configuration manager. We checked off the firewall and did not work.